# Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module '...'

Tags: angular, systemjs

Got this error : (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DossierModule'

I've got 2 ngModules importing each other, is it possible this error came from that ?
In that case : DossierModule import ContactModule, and ContactModule import DossierModule. When i remove import in ContactModule, it works, the same for DossierModule.

So 2 Modules can't import each other ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they shouldn't import each other. If the 2 modules import each other, you would end up with a circular reference. From Angular Module FAQ:

> Angular does not like modules with circular references so don't let Module 'A' import Module 'B' which imports Module 'A'.

More info: [Angular2 Module FAQ](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-reimport)

Answer (score 1):

both module import in `appmodule.ts` file like here contact module are added, you will have to add `DossierModule` and  `ContactModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ContactModule, DossierModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HighlightDirective, TitleComponent ],
  providers:    [ UserService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
```

Comment: what do you mean ?